# downloading in idm same file multiple times how to resume and download

Tags: virtualbox, debian, download, wget, microsoft-edge

I am downloading a file from a [link1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/q36j27qo7ppkjp9/macOS_Catalina_Public_Beta_by_Geekrar.zip/file).

When I click on it it generates another [link2](http://download2268.mediafire.com/rpvzc9c20i8g/q36j27qo7ppkjp9/macOS+Catalina+Public+Beta+by+Geekrar.zip) from here download begin.
I use IDM 6.35 it captures the download and I am able to download the file,
but now the fun starts I have an internet connection which keeps disconnecting.
When the connection is back and I try to download/resume the download the link sends an html page and IDM is neither able to refresh the download nor regenerated the download URL. So I have to start download again and again when ever internet connection breaks. I clicked pause/resume buttons in a hope that after downloading 2.3 GB out of 6 GB file remaining should download rather than starting from 0 again and again. Many a times I tried refreshing the link in IDM. Some how I wasted one whole day in doing this how can I download file easily.
I am following a tutorial as given [here](https://www.geekrar.com/how-to-download-macos-catalina-vmware-virtualbox-image/) to install Mac in Virtual box.
When my internet connection disrupts I get almost nothing. I pause try to resume. The only thing that works is refreshing download address I have to manually click on the link1 then it generates a new link2 then IDM asks me if this is new link to download same old file I click yes then it starts again. But this has been a very painful process. Is there any other solution or any other download manager that I should try. I need suggestions if wget in Debian would be able to do same or any other thing that may work. I have used wget previously but this sort of link generation and link capturing I have no idea if that will work in wget.I use Windows 10 mostly.
I am doing all this in Microsoft edge.

Comment: I use WS_FTP Pro (Ipswitch) for this and it can resume downloads. I have used that feature. I am not aware of any way with Edge or IE.  Occasionally the browser will pick up after a short loss of connection.

Comment: my connection loss is for more than 30 minutes or so there a lot of circus happens.

Comment: Try WS_FTP (Trial Available). See if that helps - it should

Answer (score 0):

You can use this version of IDM: https://techrechard.com/download-internet-download-manager-idm/

Let me know if that works for you.

Use this verified files to [Download macOS Catalina](https://techrechard.com/how-to-download-macos-10-15-catalina-iso-dmg-vmdk/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am not sure what the policy is for promoting bootleg copies of commercial software.  And what makes you think this will work for the OP?  Because I dont think it will.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues

1. When an internet connection is lost, you probably get allocated a different IP address.  In this case, the server is not going to continue with the download.
2. If it is giving you another link to download then it is probably a time-limited link, to avoid it being posted on other sites.  In this case, if you take too long to download or your session is lost, then you can not continue.

I think you need to find a friend with a more reliable connection.